# Project on multiple fields in C# MongoDB 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

How do you project on fields in the new MongoDB C# drivers when the fields are given in the form of a String array ?.
I could find ways to project on a single field by doing

`collection.find(filter).Project(Builders<Category>.Projection.Include(fieldName)`

How do I extend this to take an array of fields ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also extension method `Include`

```
var projection = Builders<Category>.Projection.Include(fieldList.First());
foreach (var field in fieldList.Skip(1))
{
    projection = projection.Include(field);
}
var result = await collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 4):

another way, assuming fieldList is a string enumerable is:

```
var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Combine(fieldList.Select(x => Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include(x)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way than mofenko's, you don't have to include the first column :

```
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> project = null;

foreach (string columnName in columnsToInclude)
{
    if (project == null)
    {
        project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include(columnName);
    }
    else
    {
        project = project.Include(columnName);
    }
}
```

This is for loosely typed data. If you're using classes replace `BsonDocument` with your class

Comment: Is this really better? It has more lines of code and it checks additional `if` condition for each included field